# How to automatically resize the panel in a firefox extension

Tags: resize, firefox-addon, panel, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making a firefox extension using their addon builder and I am trying to get a popup to open when I click on a toolbar button. However,it seems like the dimensions of the panel can not be set to auto. I load some content after making an api call and therefore the html content of the panel varies. How do I make the panel resize according to the html document size automatically, like the default popup in google chrome extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do the resizing manually, using the [`resize` method](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#resize%28width%2C%20height%29)

If you figure out a solution that works at auto resizing, by detecting what is optimal for the page somehow, then submit a [pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) or [submit a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK)

Comment: How do I detect what is optimal for the page? I mean I have a `contentScriptFile` that makes the api call and returns the string and populates the html of the panel. The panel however is created from the `main.js` file. How do I resize the panel then? I need to get the dimensions of the html file in the panle somehow from the `contentScriptFile` to `main.js`. How do I do it?

Comment: Thanks @erikvold for pointing me in the right direction. I got it to work using the `port.emit and port.on` methods to resize the panle.